# Use of backspace with endl and \n in C++

Tags: c++, escaping, backspace

I have written a small C++ program to understand the use of `\b`. The program is given below -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << "\b";
    return 0;
}
```

So, this program gives the desired output `Hello World`.This should not happen because backspace only moves cursor one space back and not delete it from the buffer.So,why `!` is not printed?

Now,Consider another program-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << "\b";
    cout << "\nAnother Line\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, here the output is -

`Hello World!
Another Line`

Why does the backspace does not work here? Newline should not flush the buffer,so `!` should be deleted.What is the issue here?

Also,when i add either `endl` or `\n` after `\b`,in both the cases,the output is `Hello World!`.But,newline character does not flush the buffer whereas `endl` flushes the buffer.So, how the output is same in both the cases?

Comment: You have 2 wrong assumptions:.1. _"This should not happen because backspace only moves cursor one space back ..."_. 2. _"But,newline character does not flush the buffer ..."_ The latter is implementation dependend.

Comment: When your program exits the console probably prints a prompt that overwrites the "!". Also `cout` gets flushed when your program exits regardless. How `\b` works is nothing to do with `C++`. `C++` sends all characters you tell it to the console (or whatever else it happens to be connected to). How the console behaves depends on the console.

Comment: So @πάνταῥεῖ, can using `\n` flush the buffer?

Comment: You didnt flush the buffer. Better alternative here would be using printf, or consider ::std::cerr, because its flushed when you print something.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the output from your first program looks something like this?

```
$ ./hello
Hello World$
```

If so, the `!` is not deleted from the buffer; it is clobbered when the shell prints the prompt.

With regard to the second program, when the buffer is flushed only influences when `\b` is sent to the terminal, not how it is processed.  The `\b` is a part of the stream and a terminal happens to interpret this to mean "back up one column".  If this is not clear, take a look at the actual bytes sent to *stdout*:

```
$ ./hello2 | hexdump -C
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f  72 6c 64 21 08 0a 41 6e  |Hello World!..An|
00000010  6f 74 68 65 72 20 4c 69  6e 65 0a                 |other Line.|
0000001b
```

The `\b` is followed by the `\n` (`08` and `0a` respectively), matching what you wrote to `cout` in your program.

Finally, `cout` is flushed when the program exits so it does not matter whether you pass `\n` or `endl` in this example.  In fact, `\n` will likely flush anyway since *stdout* is connected to a terminal.